# Insert value of list in xlsx file with python

Tags: python, excel

I'm tring to insert value of list in a column of xlsx file with python.

this is the code

```
def trasformazione (original):
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:3395')
transformat=[]

for g in range (0,row_count-1):
    x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,original[g][0],original[g][1])
    transformat.append([x2,y2])

return (transformat)
transformat=trasformazione (original)
print(trasformazione (original))
 # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
  workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('campioni1.xlsx')
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 # Start from the first cell below the headers.
  row = 1
 col=0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
worksheet.write(row, col,transformat)
row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Thanks for the support

Comment: Ok but what's the question/problem with your current code?

Comment: Also there are many indentation errors, can you fix them as well?

Comment: the code run error

Comment: I fix it! But I've a problem with the xlsx file in lat e long i 've the same value for the columns.